# Как сделать плавное трансформация у блока

Tags: css, анимация, css-animation

[image: картинка]

Как сделать анимацию чтобы края круглой фигуры плавно двигалось и образовался эффект.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример

```css
.benefit {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid #f00;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.benefit__text,
.benefit svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.benefit svg {
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
}

.benefit__text {
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 9;
}
```

```html
<div class="benefit">
  <span class="benefit__text">13</span>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 288 288">
    <path  fill="#f00">
      <animate repeatCount="indefinite" attributeName="d" dur="5s" values="M37.5,186c-12.1-10.5-11.8-32.3-7.2-46.7c4.8-15,13.1-17.8,30.1-36.7C91,68.8,83.5,56.7,103.4,45
    c22.2-13.1,51.1-9.5,69.6-1.6c18.1,7.8,15.7,15.3,43.3,33.2c28.8,18.8,37.2,14.3,46.7,27.9c15.6,22.3,6.4,53.3,4.4,60.2
    c-3.3,11.2-7.1,23.9-18.5,32c-16.3,11.5-29.5,0.7-48.6,11c-16.2,8.7-12.6,19.7-28.2,33.2c-22.7,19.7-63.8,25.7-79.9,9.7
    c-15.2-15.1,0.3-41.7-16.6-54.9C63,186,49.7,196.7,37.5,186z;
    
    
    M51,171.3c-6.1-17.7-15.3-17.2-20.7-32c-8-21.9,0.7-54.6,20.7-67.1c19.5-12.3,32.8,5.5,67.7-3.4C145.2,62,145,49.9,173,43.4
    c12-2.8,41.4-9.6,60.2,6.6c19,16.4,16.7,47.5,16,57.7c-1.7,22.8-10.3,25.5-9.4,46.4c1,22.5,11.2,25.8,9.1,42.6
    c-2.2,17.6-16.3,37.5-33.5,40.8c-22,4.1-29.4-22.4-54.9-22.6c-31-0.2-40.8,39-68.3,35.7c-17.3-2-32.2-19.8-37.3-34.8
    C48.9,198.6,57.8,191,51,171.3z;
    
    M37.5,186c-12.1-10.5-11.8-32.3-7.2-46.7c4.8-15,13.1-17.8,30.1-36.7C91,68.8,83.5,56.7,103.4,45
    c22.2-13.1,51.1-9.5,69.6-1.6c18.1,7.8,15.7,15.3,43.3,33.2c28.8,18.8,37.2,14.3,46.7,27.9c15.6,22.3,6.4,53.3,4.4,60.2
    c-3.3,11.2-7.1,23.9-18.5,32c-16.3,11.5-29.5,0.7-48.6,11c-16.2,8.7-12.6,19.7-28.2,33.2c-22.7,19.7-63.8,25.7-79.9,9.7
    c-15.2-15.1,0.3-41.7-16.6-54.9C63,186,49.7,196.7,37.5,186z  " />
    </path>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Подробное описание - [Morphing using SVG](https://webkul.com/blog/morphing-using-svg-animate-css/)

Comment: Спасибо,это то что надо было!!!Круто очень!!!Скажите пожалуйста а как сделали это,с помощь генераторов или как ?